# Display different value if there are more then 5 locations in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<p class="country" data-country="UK">lon</p>
<p class="country" data-country="UK">lon</p>
<p class="country" data-country="UK">lon</p>
<p class="country" data-country="UK">lon</p>
<p class="country" data-country="UK">lon</p>

<p class="country" data-country="IT">milan</p>
<p class="country" data-country="IT">milan</p>
```

and I would like to have that changed to:

```
 <p> various UK location</p> (based on having more the 5 cities for the same country)

<p class="country" data-country="IT">milan</p>
<p class="country" data-country="IT">milan</p>
```

so far I have:

```
var countries = [];

$("p.country").each(function(){
    countries.push($(this).data("country")); 
});

var unqiueCountries = countries.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return countries.indexOf(item) == pos;
}) // get unique values per country


for(var i =0; i < unqiueCountries.length; i++ ){
    $("p.country").each(function(){
        if($(this).data('country') == unqiueCountries[i]) { // as long as the countries match check if there are more then 5 locations
            if ($(this).data('country').length >= 5) {
                console.log('various location');
            }
        }
    })
}
```

something in the logic is not working as expected.

Comment: if ($(this).data('country').length >= 5) -> you are data checking string length... https://jsfiddle.net/8puy3ub6/  and it is always two...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `$(this).data('country').length` is always 2 in your code, because it is the length of the value in the data attribute. It does not in any way correspond to the number of elements with the same attribute value.

But you don't need that much code to perform this operation:

```js
$("p.country").each(function() {
    var country = $(this).data("country"),
        $match = $('[data-country="' + country +'"]');
    if ($match.length < 5) return;
    $(this).before($("<p>").text("various " + country + " locations"));
    $match.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="country" data-country="UK">lon</p>
<p class="country" data-country="UK">lon</p>
<p class="country" data-country="UK">lon</p>
<p class="country" data-country="UK">lon</p>
<p class="country" data-country="UK">lon</p>

<p class="country" data-country="IT">milan</p>
<p class="country" data-country="IT">milan</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I will do that in the following way:

```js
var countries = [];
$("p.country").each(function(){
    countries.push($(this).data("country")); 
});
var unqiueCountries = countries.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return countries.indexOf(item) == pos;
});

unqiueCountries.forEach(function(item){
  var pElement = document.querySelectorAll("[data-country="+item+"]");
  if(pElement.length >= 5){
    $(pElement).remove();
    $('body').prepend("<p> various UK location</p>");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="country" data-country="UK">lon</p>
<p class="country" data-country="UK">lon</p>
<p class="country" data-country="UK">lon</p>
<p class="country" data-country="UK">lon</p>
<p class="country" data-country="UK">lon</p>

<p class="country" data-country="IT">milan</p>
<p class="country" data-country="IT">milan</p>
```